# facebook api with private message multiple to (friends)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I development facebook private message for invite with facebook api.

```
<script>
    FB.init({ appId: 'xxxxxxxxxx', xfbml: true, cookie: true });
    FB.ui({
        method: 'send',
        to: ['1736383768','590528674'],

        // picture: 'http://thinkdiff.net/iphone/lucky7_ios.jpg',
        //Can be page, popup, iframe, or touch. 
        display: 'popup',
        name: 'yyyyyy',
        link: '<%=Request.QueryString["link"]%>'
    });

 </script>
```

but adds only the first mate.

how to multiple friends send private message ?

Comment: [Refer this link about multiple posting][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345467/facebook-post-to-multiple-friends-walls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   var publish = 

    {
              method: 'stream.publish',
              message: 'Some kind of test',
              uid: uid,
              attachment: {
                name: 'Test',
                caption: 'Facebook API Test',
                description: ('Sure hope it worked!'),
                href: 'http://www.test.com/',
                media: [
                  {
                    type: 'image',
                    href: 'http://test.com/',
                    src: 'http://test.com/image.jpg'
                  }
                ]
              },
              action_links: [
                { text: 'Your text', href: 'http://www.test.com/' }
              ],
              user_prompt_message: 'Share your thoughts about test'
    };

    publish.target_id = friendID;
    FB.ui(publish);

    publish.target_id = friendID;
    FB.ui(publish);

            return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use stream.publish.
As said by facebook : "We are in the process of deprecating the REST API, so if you are building a new application you shouldn't use this function. Instead use the Graph API and POST a Post object to the `feed` connection of the User object"

So, now you have the [send](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) and feed methods left.

You cannot fill the send method with more than one user id (you can only if you are whitelisted by facebook, but I'm not quite sur how to do this , I would not count on it either).

You can use the feed method to post on many user's friends wall with something like this

```
FB.api('/USERID/feed', 'post', {
  name:postName,
  link:postLink,
  picture:postPicture,
  description:postDescription,
  message:postMessage
}, function (postResponse) { //DO SOMETHING HERE });
```

But doing it, you are taking the risk of your app being deleted by facebook if someone flag it as spam.

As far as I know, sending messages to multiple friends via an App is considered bad/spam by facebook so they do not allow this anymore.

You still can Invite as many friends as you want via the [App request dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) (method apprequests) but I'm not sure this is what you want.